# If conditional "didn't" vs "hadn't"

Tags: grammar, conditionals

Grammar rules say that *hadn't* is used for unreal past conditions, but why can't we use simple past negation instead of past perfect?

> If I hadn't come to the meeting, it wouldn't have happened.
>
> If I didn't come to the meeting, it wouldn't happen.

Does the second sentence also imply that "I did come, that's why it happened"?

Answer (score 5):

The past simple in *if-clauses* has three functions:

1. to indicate that something is not true (contrafactual):

   - If I had time, I would help you. (but I don't have time)
   - If I didn't know you were joking, I'd be angry. (but I do know you're joking)
2. to hypothesise about the future (but conveying that you regard the possibility as remote):

   - If I won a lot of money, I'd retire.
   - If I didn't attend the meeting, I'd probably get the sack.
3. to refer to habitual past events:

   - If I was late, he would make me work through lunch.
   - If I didn't eat my greens, I got no dessert.

Your sentence (*If I didn't come to the meeting, it wouldn't happen*) belongs either in category 2. For example:

- If I didn't come *(go is more likely)* to the meeting, it wouldn't happen (e.g. I wouldn't get my monthly bonus.) - but I'm definitely planning to attend.

Or in category 3:

- *If (whenever) I didn't come to the meeting, it wouldn't happen (I wouldn't get my monthly bonus.)*

The sentence *If I didn't come to the meeting, it wouldn't have happened* is ungrammatical.

Comment: Shoe- Michael Swan's Practical Usage has a sentence stating that it's commonly used in AE. "If I didn't have my walking boots on I think I would have really hurt my foot"

Comment: @Noah, Perhaps an American could comment on whether this construction is common in AE. I wasn't able to find the reference in Swan. Could you tell me which page it is on?

Comment: That construction sounds wrong to me, although possibly it is used in some regions of the U.S.

Comment: @Shoe Page 262(Mixed Tenses 6)

Comment: @Noah, I can't find the sentence in my copy of Swan (second edition, published in 1997) and can find no section on mixed tenses. Anyway, I can say with some assurance that in BE *If I didn't come to the meeting, it wouldn't happen* cannot ever mean *If I hadn't come to the meeting, it wouldn't have happened* (which I think was your original question). And that *If I didn't come to the meeting, it wouldn't have happened* is ungrammatical (the claim in my OP). I await with interest any American commenter who refutes these claims.

Comment: @Shoe It's the third edition. Not sure about the second edition because I don't have it at hand.

Comment: @Shoe: Could you tell me if this is correct: "By the time I would realize, it would have taken 4 hours(Talking about past)" This one doesn't have an if statement, but I am not sure if it's the correct way of saying it. As it's kind of related to this post, I don't want to create a new question.

Comment: @Noah. Thanks. Seems like I'll have to invest in the latest Swan! The sentence is your last post appears incomplete (or I haven't understood the intended meaning.) A correct example based on your fragment would be: "By the time I realized that it would take 4 hours, it was too late to stop."

Comment: @Shoe- Thanks. The action is of a behavioral type. Like I would get in a chat with a friend every once in a while, and when by the time I would realize, it would take 4 hours. Am I using it properly this time?

Comment: Yes, you can say something like "*By the time I would realize, it would have taken 4 hours*" but the *would* in both clauses is the habitual *would* not the conditional *would*. Another example is: *We would chat for ages before we would realize how much time had passed.* Although in this case I prefer to use the simple past in the second clause: *We would chat for ages before we realized how much time had passed.*

Comment: @Shoe- Thanks. What is the difference between "By the time I would realize, it would have taken 4 hours" and "By the time I would realize, it would take 4 hours". Are both the same? In BTW, both your examples seem identical.

Comment: @Noah, The difference in my sentences is between *we would realize* and *we realized*. There is a difference between your 2 sentences: "By the time I would realize, it would have taken 4 hours" and "By the time I would realize, it would take 4 hours"  but I need more space than a comment allows to give a good answer.

Comment: @Shoe- Thanks. Posted a new question. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60277/difference-between-would-have-and-would-in-the-following

Comment: One comment. Michael Swan's example from *Practical Usage,* "If I didn't have my walking boots on, I think I would have really hurt my foot," ***does not*** use the simple past for a past condition. If an American said that sentence, he would ***still*** have his walking boots on. So unreal present condition and hypothetical past event. It's not the most formal grammar, but I suspect Swan is right, and it's used.

Comment: @Peter, Speaking as an American, I regret to inform you that we're well on the way to using past in place of conditional. "If I didn't have my walking boots on" *CAN* certainly mean that I have them on at the time of the speech act, but it is just as likely to mean "If I hadn't had my walking boots on [yesterday]..."

Answer (score 2):

Your first sentence is an example of what you may have heard called the **Third Conditional**. It is used to express something that didn’t actually happen. Your second sentence, on the other hand, is an example of the **Second Conditional**, which expresses something that is still possible, but which is unlikely.

It’s easier to see the difference with sentences that are positive rather than negative, as these three examples may show.

**First Conditional:** 'If you run you will catch the train'. This predicts a likely event: running will certainly allow you to catch the train.

**Second Conditional:** 'If you ran, you would catch the train.' This suggests that the person addressed is unlikely to run.

**Third Conditional:** 'If you had run, you would have caught the train.' The person addressed didn’t run.

Answer (score 1):

"If I didn't come to the meeting" could reference the future.

Comment: +1: I'd go further than that and say "didn't" in OP's second version could *only* reference the future. In most cases you'd say *"If I didn't **go** to the meeting"*, but it's just about possible to use "come" in certain contexts.

Comment: I guess I was think colloquially, but it brings up an interesting question about the use of come and go and their usage in temporal and spatial locations. I feel a question brewing.

Comment: I await that with interest! I'm sure there are different connotations/contexts, but I shan't bash my brains out on it unless and until I see your question!

Answer (score 1):

Reading the comments on another answer, the OP took the sentence from Michael Swan's *Practical Usage:*

> If I didn't have my walking boots on, I think I would have really hurt my foot,

and extrapolating from it, asked whether simple past can be used in conditional statements rather than past perfect for unreal past conditions. The answer is "no". An American would only say that sentence if he *still* had his walking boots on. So this is a statement with an unreal present condition, and a past consequence. This construction is rare, because consequences tend to occur after the hypotheticals.

Is this construction grammatical in the U.S.? I suspect you would get disagreement among Americans about that. However, I believe that Swan is right about it being used.

Comment: Does it mean that *"If I didn't have my walking boots on, I think I would have really hurt my foot"* and *"If I hadn't had my walking boots on, I think I would have really hurt my foot"* convey different meaning?

Comment: @Noan: yes, although it's not much of a difference.

Comment: How about another example from Swan. "If I knew you were coming I'd have baked a cake."

Comment: @igor_g: Now you've stumped me, because that example sounds okay (although informal), whereas the seemingly similar "If I went over the Tappan Zee Bridge, we wouldn't have gotten stuck in this traffic" sounds horribly wrong.